# Detect Windows 10 S-Mode in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

I am developing the windows store application that need to detect whether windows 10 is in secure mode or not.  Is there any API call to detect windows 10 operating system in S-mode or not?

Comment: Secure mode is often used for debugging system failure (fail to boot, virus), is it what you are talking about? And how does it affects the deployment of the app?

Comment: I suspect you can do this using EasClientDeviceInformation or possibly ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent, but I haven't been able to confirm as it seems there is no way to side-load a (non-store) app in S-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try using windowsintegritypolicy from windows 10 RS5, 17763 build onwards. Otherwise, there is winapi function call in wldp.dll wldpgetlockdownpolicy which outputs the values of s mode as enums.